# There is any option to remove underline from anchors in html emails

Tags: css, outlook, gmail, signature, yahoo-mail

It's a signature and need to remove it, it's shows up in gmail,yahoo and outlook.com added text-decoration: none !important;. 
it's ignoring the :

```
.ii a[href] {
    color: #15c;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

in gmail.
The Signature is created with outlook.
I think i tried everything but its still shows up:

```
body {
    font-family: Tahoma;
}

p {
    font-family: Tahoma;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-family: Tahoma;
}
.ii a[href] {
    color: #15c;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
#yiv2739675612 a:visited, #yiv2739675612 span.yiv2739675612MsoHyperlinkFollowed {
text-decoration: none !important;
}
.ExternalClass a:link, .ExternalClass span.ecxMsoHyperlink {
text-decoration: none !important;
}
.c-ReadMessagePartBody .ExternalClass a:link {
text-decoration: none !important;
}
#yiv2739675612 a:link, #yiv2739675612 span.yiv2739675612MsoHyperlink {
text-decoration: none !important;
}
.undoreset a, .undoreset a:hover {
text-decoration: none !important;
}
span {
text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Comment: What about inline styles?  e.g., `<a href="javascript:void(0)" style="text-decoration:none;">A Link</a>

I've never had any luck with external reference styles in email.

Comment: i tried inline styles still not working

Comment: Where and when does it show?

Comment: the underline shows up in gmail and outlook.com